# Python get ansible msg output as a var

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible

Im using python3 and ansible 2.9.2 , 
i use python script to run the playbooks:

```
subprocess.Popen(["ansible-playbook",  "create.yml"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I get the output as a string :

```
"(b'\nPLAY [localhost] **\n\nTASK [Creating abc] ***\nok: [localhost]\n\nTASK [debug] ***\nok: [localhost] => {\n    "msg": "10.0.0.1"\n}\n\nPLAY RECAP ******\nlocalhost  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   \n\n', b"[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'\n[WARNING]: Found variable using reserved name: name\n")"
```

How can i filter only the "msg" output in python ?

I want to get the ip address `10.0.0.1` as a variable and couldnt find the right regex to catch it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the ansible output (result of playbook) does not change from this syntax in 2.9.2, I would use something like this in order to catch the ip as variable:

```py
import json

long_output = '''"(b'\nPLAY [localhost] **\n\nTASK [Creating abc] ***\nok: [localhost]\n\nTASK [debug] ***\nok: [localhost] => {\n    "msg": "10.0.0.1"\n}\n\nPLAY RECAP ******\nlocalhost  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   \n\n', b"[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'\n[WARNING]: Found variable using reserved name: name\n")"'''

cut_string = json.loads(long_output.split("=> ")[1].split('PLAY RECAP')[0])
print(cut_string)
```

## OUTPUT:

```py
{'msg': '10.0.0.1'}
```

And then do this little trick to catch all the IP addresses as list: (Maybe for future use if you going to run the playbook on more than one destination)

```py
ip_addresses = [ip for ip in dict(cut_string).values()]
print(ip_addresses)
```

## OUTPUT:

```py
['10.0.0.1']
```

Hope you'll find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already launching a playbook from a python script, I recommend [Ansible Runner](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner).